# Heroku Bandwidth Limit Exceeded

Tags: heroku

Please, try to acess:

http://unidemico.herokuapp.com/

It is working the index page, but when I'm trying to acess any Available controller:

Available Controllers:

unidemico.AreaAcademicaController
unidemico.ArtigoController

I get the following error:

Bandwidth Limit Exceeded

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to the site owner reaching his/her bandwidth limit. Please try again later.
Apache Server at www.changeme.com Port 80

Any Idea why?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits

I have no idea if I exceed any limit its the first time I deploy an application and its a Grails application very simple, only two controllers, project has only 2Mb...

Comment: Should the domain be pointing to changeme.com or is there something in your config that still needs to be updated?

Comment: I have no idea where this changeme comes from :( do you have any idea?

Comment: // set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }

}

I just find out this configuration inside Config.groovy, it means my application is trying to redirect to this domain changeme, I dont have a registered domain, dont heroku have a free domain?

Comment: I changed the grails.serverURL = "changeme.com" to my heroku app's domain... now it's working fine! thanks for helping me

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`changeme.com` is a placeholder domain. You need to update your `Config.groovy` to point to your heroku app domain or your custom domain.